# Stop job that work under launchd temporarily in Mac OS

Tags: macos, launchd

I have **Redis** job that installed under launchd.

In order to check how my app work without Redis I want to stop one for a moment.

```
$launchctl stop homebrew.redis # => redis down and up right away
```

I know command `launchctl unload path_to_plist` but it's not solution for me.

**Does the solution without unloading plist exist?**

Comment: @unhillbilly, Sure, but the reason of the question is ability to stop a job temporarily regardless of plist (i fogger path to plist often).

Comment: I tried it, but it not works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think **no**.

`launchctl unload` is the only way to temporarily stop the service in OS X.